# What names/strings are available in RoutedEvent

Tags: xaml

I've seen some examples in XAML such as

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Ellipse.Loaded">
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
```

However, what I can't see is how I know what string I can use...

For example, assume I want to add an event on the MouseOut event, would I use MouseOut, OnMouseOut, MouseLeave, OnMouseLeave etc

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
```

The only reason I know to use MouseLeave is that I happen to have found it on the SO site...

Please consider the following, which will fire when a new item is "pushed" into a bound `ObservableCollection<T>`  ... I'm not sure why the event is Loaded, and not "Added"

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                     <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.ScaleX" From="0" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                 </Storyboard>
             </BeginStoryboard>
         </EventTrigger.Actions>
     </EventTrigger>
 </Style.Triggers>
```

How would I achieve the same event on Delete where I'd like the Item to transformed in a different manner?

Comment: "which will fire when a new item is "pushed" into a bound ObservableCollection<T>". That's not the direct cause of the Loaded event. Instead the [Loaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded(v=vs.110).aspx) event is fired when a FrameworkElement is loaded, i.e. *when the element is laid out, rendered, and ready for interaction*. Besides that, there is no MouseOut event. It's called MouseLeave. [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement_events(v=vs.110).aspx) for a list of all FrameworkElement events.

Comment: @Clemens, Thank you, your comment is 90% of the answer I was looking for. The last 10% is, how do I know (via the RoutedEvent) what has occurred? In the question, I've essentially trying to detect if List has had an item added or removed. Or is the answer, I can't using RoutedEvents as it's only about the Framework element (Loaded in this case)

Comment: Well, there's obviously also an Unloaded event.

Comment: Wait... Now I'm lost. But the framework element isn't unloaded? Just "updated". edit - hang on, is each item in the ListItem considered a framework element?

Comment: Sure, every item is displayed by a so-called item container, e.g. a `ListBoxItem` in a ListBox. ListBoxItem is a FrameworkElement.

Comment: I was so focused on the ObservableCollection I just didn't consider it... Please move to an answer? It's **exactly** what I was looking for @Clemens